# statistical comparison, 3 groups, multiple columns

Tags: analysis, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra

I am using R for some statistical analysis. I have a dataset listing number of deaths by eu regions. the dataset is annual and is for 2000-2008. I divided this data into 4 subgroups according to number of deaths.

1. very high
2. high
3. medium
4. low

the dataset looks like this (random numbers):

```
1 2000 2001 2002 region
2 10    12   11  Bawaria
3 50    ..   ..
4 30
5 .. 
...
```

I want to compare how the difference looked between regions depending on a group it is classified to. Whether the regions in the VERY HIGH group changed more (UP or DOWN) than the regions with LOW ranking of deaths. So apart from the groups I want to include years into statistics.

The groups contain different number of values, from 10 to 200. I understand I need to take samples from 200? What to do next?

Can anyone help me how to approach it?

many thanks !

Comment: This is a repeated messurements design. First Factor(region) x rmFactor(year)